# Updating variable after each iteration of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, first of all I would like to say that I'm just getting started with angular so this is probably very trivial question.

Let's say I have js file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.pool=10;
        $scope.array=[1,3,5]

}
```

and ng-repeat

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in array" ng-init="pool=pool-x">
      {{pool}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example variable `pool` equals 10 at the start of every iteration and I want it to be updated so the result could be `9,6,1` and not `9,7,5`. How to achieve that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a known pitfall in angular, the issue is angular uses something known as `scope inheritance`, which means each itration of `ng-repeat` creates a new scope with a property `pool`.

and changing the value of that property would only effect the inner scope, becase it is a diffrent variable.

instead you should use **a reference** to a non-primitive value (such as Object):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.obj = { pool: 10 };
  $scope.pool = 10;
  $scope.array = [1,3,5];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in array" ng-init="pool=pool-x;obj.pool=obj.pool-x;newvar=obj.pool">
      {{pool}} *** {{newvar}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Im guessing that primitive pool isn't needed anymore

Comment: Oh, that was just for a educational purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ng-init` will only be called once, its an initialization directive, so you can try this, I have not tested but it should work:

```
// In you controller
$scope.changePool = function(val) {
    $scope.pool -= val;
}
<div ng-repeat="x in array; changePool(x)">
   {{pool}}
</div>

<!-- or this -->
<div ng-repeat="x in array">
   {{changePool(x)}}
</div>
```